# Neurosky: Mindwave mobile- is it possible to access Raw data from the headset?

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

If anyone has knowledge of **NeuroSky** products...

Is it possible to access the **raw data** from the Mindwave mobile headset?

I ask as I would like to access that data (i.e. theta, gamma waves etc) in order to perform calculations on it.

The following is the **android** sample code provided by NeuroSky:

Code section relating to raw eeg data: (As you can see, nothing is done to access the raw data)

```
case TGDevice.MSG_RAW_DATA:
                /* Handle raw EEG/EKG data here */
                break;
```

Full sample code activity:

```
package com.test.helloeeg;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.neurosky.thinkgear.*;

public class HelloEEGActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "HelloEEG"; //??

    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter; //BluetoothAdapter lets you perform fundamental Bluetooth tasks
    TGDevice device; //used to manage a single connection to a single hardware device

    final boolean rawEnabled = true; //??

    //references to the layout
    ScrollView sv;
    TextView tv;
    Button b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //set up the scroll views and text boxes
        sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText("");
        //display what android version is being used
        tv.append("Android version: " + Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) + "\n");

        // Check if Blue tooth is available on the Android device
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {

            // Alert user that Bluetooth is not available
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            // finish();
            return;

        } else {

            // create the TGDevice
            //Android app is connecting to hardware device using the standard constructor
            device = new TGDevice(bluetoothAdapter, handler);
        }

        tv.append("NeuroSky: " + TGDevice.version + " " + TGDevice.build_title);
        tv.append("\n");

    }

    /* end onCreate() */

    // turn off app when touch return button of phone
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            device.close();
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        // Intent enableIntent = new
        // Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        // startActivityForResult(enableIntent, 1);
        // }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // device.close();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        device.close();
        super.onStop();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // device.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * Handles messages from TGDevice
     * 
     */
    final Handler handler = new Handler() { //Note: TGdevice communicates with app messages sent to handler object
                                            //A handler object processes incoming data
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            //msg.what determines the type of each message
            switch (msg.what) {
            case TGDevice.MSG_STATE_CHANGE:

                //actual value of the message is determined by msg.arg1
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case TGDevice.STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    tv.append("Connecting...\n");
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    tv.append("Connected.\n");
                    device.start();
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_NOT_FOUND:
                    tv.append("Could not connect any of the paired BT devices.  Turn them on and try again.\n");
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_ERR_NO_DEVICE:
                    tv.append("No Bluetooth devices paired.  Pair your device and try again.\n");
                    break;
                case TGDevice.STATE_ERR_BT_OFF:
                    tv.append("Bluetooth is off.  Turn on Bluetooth and try again.");
                    break;

                case TGDevice.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    tv.append("Disconnected.\n");
                } /* end switch on msg.arg1 */

                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_POOR_SIGNAL:
                tv.append("PoorSignal: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");
                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_HEART_RATE:
                tv.append("Heart rate: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");
                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_RAW_DATA:
                /* Handle raw EEG/EKG data here */
                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_ATTENTION:
                tv.append("Attention: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");

                //Example code to see modifications
                if(msg.arg1>=30){

                    tv.append("getting nearer!!");
                }

                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_MEDITATION:
                tv.append("Meditation: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");
                break;

            case TGDevice.MSG_BLINK:
                tv.append("Blink: " + msg.arg1 + "\n");
                break;

            default:
                break;

            } /* end switch on msg.what */

            sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

        } /* end handleMessage() */

    }; /* end Handler */

    /**
     * This method is called when the user clicks on the "Connect" button.
     * 
     * @param view
     */
    public void doStuff(View view) {
        //if the device is not currently connecting and is not already connected
        if (device.getState() != TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTING
                && device.getState() != TGDevice.STATE_CONNECTED) {

            //Connect the device to the Neurosky Headset (starting connection process)
            device.connect(rawEnabled); //note: rawEnabled allows raw sample data to be sent to device


        }

    } /* end doStuff() */

} /* end HelloEEGActivity() */
```

Comment: If this isnt a suitable place to ask this question, please re direct me to a different address!

Answer (score 0):

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case TGDevice.MSG_RAW_MULTI:

                TGRawMulti eegRaw = (TGRawMulti) msg.obj;

                double ch1 = eegRaw.ch1;
                double ch2 = eegRaw.ch2;
                double ch3 = eegRaw.ch3;
                double ch4 = eegRaw.ch4;
                double ch5 = eegRaw.ch5;
                double ch6 = eegRaw.ch6;
                double ch7 = eegRaw.ch7;
                double ch8 = eegRaw.ch8;

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for providing a solution. However, just providing code without any explanation is not a good style. Could you please edit your question and add a short explanation?